# Get register date with Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get the date when user first joined Facebook with Graph (or any other) API. In an older post (sorry, can't find the link now) I have read that it is not possible and it is even removed from profiles; however recently with timeline it is added to the profile, so the data is somehow available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, not possible.  It's been asked many times here on SO.  The closest you can get is a guess by paginating thru the user's wall/stream until you get to the last item.

Comment: i had a slight hope that things have changed with timeline feature :)